# Why relative module import is so confused in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm a JavaScript developer and now learning python programing. But python's module import
mechanism confuses me a lot.

For example, I have a following projects folder:

```
├── src
│   ├── utils
│   │   ├── u1.xx
│   │   └── u2.xx
│   └── core
│       └── service.xx
│   
└── setup.xx
```

in which, `service.xx` uses a function in `../utils/u1.xx`, and `setup.xx` will execute `./scr/core/service.xx`.

In JavaScript, I just need write a relative importing code basing on current file path. as following:

```js
// src/core/service.js

import u1 from "../utils/u1.js"

export default function () {
  u1()
}
```

```js
// setup.js

import service from "./src/core/service.js"

service()
```

they can be executed at everywhere, and needn't consider executing path:

```bash
node setup.xx
node src/core/service.xx
```

In python, It's so complex.

```py
# setup.py

from src.core import service

service.service()
```

```py
// src/core/service.py

from ..utils import u1


def service():
    u1.say()
```

I can execute `python3 setup.py` successfully, but can't `python3 src/core/service.py`.

How to write python relative importing statement as JavaScript, so I can execute every script at everywhere. Because I use python to do some scientific data analysis and plot some plots, every script needs to be executed separately. and they also may depend on common functions (like `../utils/xxx`).

I have read many posts, the most solution is using `sys.path` but it may pollute global naming space. Is there any other solution?

Comment: In short, throw away all your pre-conceptions, assume python is weird, and attempt to follow best practices. ```sys.path``` is _not_ a good practice. flake8 (and likely other linters) will prompt you not to place logic above imports. I've come to accept the knowledge distilled in the linters as excellent advice.